# Accessing member variables from a derived class in C++

Tags: c++, oop

Im currently learning OOP in C++.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}

protected:
    SomeClass variable;
};


class Child : public Base {
public:
    Child() {}

    void method() {
        // Access variable
    }
};
```

**When accessing a member variable in the base class from a derived class, what is the difference between these two notations?**

- `this->variable`
- `Base::variable`

And what is preferred when?

Comment: also just `variable` is an option

Comment: 1. No difference, whatsover, and 2. The problem with asking ten C++ developers what is the preferred way to do something will result in fifteen different answers.

Comment: Not even a differenece when `SomeClass` is inherited to a `ChildSomeClass` that is used in some child class of `Child` again?

Comment: In general I'd suggest keeping the Base:: form reserved for static variables (unless required due to otherwise not being accessible) so a reader quickly recognizes that this is a static variable.

Comment: @AlexGeorg what happens when you need the `Base::` but it's not a static member?

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, I just edited a remark regarding that. Sometimes you have no choice (which is a bit annoying by the C++ language).

Comment: @AlexGeorg But then people quickly *incorrectly assume* that it's static

Comment: @Caleth Those cases are luckily rare enough. From my experience it's already quite established/intuitive to see that usage as static on first glance. Whether the particular case is actually one is hopefully clear from the context or a comment. The opposite to assume that all variables are non-static would be just as bad, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 6):

The "full" expression naming that variable is:

```
this->Base::variable
```

It says:

1. The name is `variable`
2. It lives in the type `Base`
3. The object owning this instance is `this`

Since you're inside a scope where base members will be found automatically, you don't need `Base::`.

And, since you're inside a member function where *all* members will be found automatically, you don't need `this->`.

You might need `Base::` to disambiguate from some other `variable` in scope, but the `this->` part likely takes care of that for you already.

So, usually, you only need any of the following:

1. `variable` (normally)
2. `this->variable` (if something from another scope is hiding it)
3. `Base::variable` (if something in the current type is hiding it)

As for what's "preferred"… as long as you've satisfied your *needs*, you can do whatever you like. But simpler is usually deemed "better", and will invite fewer questions from others reading your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third option missing: Just `variable`.

> And what is preferred when?

The one that is most pleasing to your aesthetics.

There are some cases in which some of the options won't work. In such cases, it is preferable to use those that do work. Examples are: Plain variable name cannot be used if it has been shadowed by another variable. Qualified name cannot be used in some cases where the base depends on a template variable.